# regex, number without spaces

Tags: c++, regex, regex-negation

I am working with the regex, but I have a problem in a part of one of them.
I want to capture a number that has no intervening spaces.
I have my tests with:

- 1
- 1 1.1
- 5655 8 888 8888 888888 8
- 1 5.15
- 1.1
- 5 .5
- 5

my regex ist

```
(\d+(?:(?:\ *.\ *)\d+)*)(?:\ *)
```

What i want is that the first,5,6,7 ends up in the capture group.

The 2,3,4 should not meet the requirements because they have spaces between numbers.

the objective is that when detecting something that is not a number or a point, that test line is no longer taken into account.

Comment: What do you mean by "the  first 5,6,7" and "The 2,3,4"? If you meant your list entries, then please format as a numbered list instead of a bulleted list. Also, can you clarify what you mean by "no intervening spaces"? Your `5 .5` has a space in it.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, it sounds like you are want to match the first unbroken float number (made up of digits and points) on each line, inside a capturing group. This should do it:

```
^([\d\.]+)
```

(One or more digits or points immediately following the start of a line)

You can see it working on your sample data at https://regex101.com/r/H4Ul4i/1.

I guess you may also want to allow for non-numeric content before the first number on the line, so that for example `1` is captured in `hello 1 5.15`. For that you could use:

```
 ^(?:[^\d\.]*)([\d\.]+)
```

(Any number of non-digit/point characters after start of line ignored before capturing first continuous sequence of digit/points)

You can see this one at https://regex101.com/r/BPZGur/1.

Comment: Your regex matches all of OPs data but they specifically say that lines 2,3 and 4 should not match

Comment: Typically a regex for matching numbers needs to be a bit smarter. For instance, `00`, `01`, `00009.00` might not be desirable matches. Your regex also happily matches `.......` or `.1.2.3.4.5.`. There's no mention of negatives, but that's often a requirement. `(0|[+-]?[1-9]\d*)?(\.\d+)?` may be approaching something more like matching a number.